# AWS RDS sync realtime with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, amazon-rds

I have been tasked to complete syncing of two databases data with realtime updates to them whenever a change happens. Since our primary database is hosted on Amazon RDS (PostgreSQL) and our secondary frontend (apps and others) are on mongodb, we need to send an event every time there is a data change within the row of the table. We are currently using a websocket to do this, but that is still slow. Is there any better way of doing this?